# How to generate a "label_click" event on flowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, label, click, flowlayoutpanel

I got a problem programming a table who need to have a certain number of panel.
First of all i created a base FLP as container for others FLP, then i created 1 FLP as start for the others (i tryed to do it on the form,without FLP container, but it didnt worked, dunno rly why :/), using this code:

```
private void GeneratePanel()
    {
        if (fLContainerPanelApp.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            fLContainerPanelApp.Controls.Clear();
            listPanel.Clear();
        }
        //fLContainerPanelApp.Controls.Clear();
        //listPanel.Clear();

        listPanel.Add(fLPanelApp1);
        int numfLPanel = 83;
        for (int i = 1; i <= numfLPanel; i++)
        {
            var panel = new FlowLayoutPanel
            {
                Name = $"fLPanelApp{i+1}",
                Size = new Size(122, 27),
                BackColor = Color.DarkSalmon,
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            };
            listPanel.Add(panel);
        }
        foreach (FlowLayoutPanel item in listPanel)
        {
            fLContainerPanelApp.Controls.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

then i wanted to add 2 label for each FLP, and set different backColors, so the user can click on each of them separately. I used this code:

```
private void GenerateLbl()
    {
        int x = 1;
        foreach (FlowLayoutPanel item in listPanel)
        {
            var lblLeft = new Label
            {
                Name = $"lblLeft{x}",
                Text = $"AAA{x}",
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                BackColor = Color.DarkSalmon,
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                Font = new Font("Century Gothic", 15, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point),
                ForeColor = Color.Black,
                AutoSize = false,
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            };

            item.Controls.Add(lblLeft);
            x++;
            lblLeft.Click += lbl_Click;
        }
    }

private void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lblClicked = (Label)sender;
        MessageBox.Show($"You Pressed {lblClicked.Name}",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
```

For the moment i tryied with 1 label, but the result is that i have all the FLP properly created but without any label T_T.

Could someone help me?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Are you calling `GenerateLbl()`? ...after `GeneratePanel()`?

Comment: yes i did it.
This is just an example solution where im doing the tests. Anyway i need it to run at form_Load, or whenever the user change date (since it is for a daily appointment)

Comment: Remove `Dock = DockStyle.Fill`.

Comment: it worked like this but its no centered as if dock... pretty ugly :/

Comment: It doesn't make sense to dock in a `FlowLayoutPanel`, even if it worked.